# MVC equivalent of jQuery.load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been doing some searching and can't quite find what I'm after.

I'm working on an Umbraco project and need to render the contents of a specific page inside a parent page.

I tried

```
@Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController")
```

but this caused the assigned content item of my page to be null (because I've gone to the action rather than going to the umbraco url) which isn't really a big surprise.

Is there a `Html` method like `Action` that accepts a url instead of an action name and controller name?

I'm after something like this

```
@Html.LoadUrl("~/my-controller-section/my-action-page")
```

I could write an extension myself to do it, but was really hoping that there would already be something built into MVC to do this.  I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery to render the second page on the parent?

Comment: Because I want it to work even if javascript isn't enabled.  If there's a way of doing it on the server side that'd be preferable.

Comment: Only other way I can see is by building your own extension.

Comment: I've done that for the time being, there must be a better way.

Comment: A partial view won't work?

Comment: So you want the server to detect that javascript is disabled, and therefore, render a page contents, otherwise don't render them so javascript can render them?

Comment: @ErikPhilips no, I just want it to be handled on the server side.  There's no need to use javascript here.  I prefer to only use javascript as an enhancement to the page and always have a valid fallback.  That way everyone gets a proper user experience.

Comment: @MikeCheel I need to render the response from a URL, an action or partial won't do it because I need the CMS to do it's magic (i.e. it will fill in the CMS variables correctly).  This only happens when the page is accessed via it's advertised URL rather than by invoking the action (I hope this makes sense).  So in short I need something that behaves like `@Html.Action` but that accepts a URL instead of an Action and Controller name.

Comment: The page you need to render is not part of the MVC Project I take it (not a contoller/action within the same MVC Project)?

Comment: It's part of Umbraco (a CMS system).  It does use an action and a controller, but must be accessed via the url for Umbraco to do pull in the CMS content properly.  So it is part of the project but can't be called via the action alone (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that there isn't a way to do this in MVC so I've reluctantly rolled my own.  If a built in way of doing this comes to light I'll swap it out.

I've implemented the LoadUrl method that I proposed in my question, it's consumed like this:

```
@Html.LoadUrl("http://foo/bar")
```

The implementation looks like this (sorry it's a bit long, but I wanted to include a full working example so you can just copy and paste it).

You'll notice that I set the authentication cookie on the request, otherwise it'll just return the login page instead of the requested page.  I've specifically implemented this for Forms Authentication.  This part isn't required if your site doesn't use authentication.

```
public static class MvcExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes a request to the specified url and returns the result as an HTML string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="thisHtml">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
    /// <param name="url">The url to invoke the request on.</param>
    /// <returns>The url contents as an HTML string.</returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString LoadUrl(this HtmlHelper thisHtml, string url)
    {
        //get the url as an absolute url
        UrlHelper helper = GetUrlHelper();
        url = helper.Absolute(url);

        var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        //set the auth cookie so we don't just get the login page
        request.SetAuthenticationCookie();
        //get the response
        string responseString = request.GetResponseString();
        //return it as an html string
        return new MvcHtmlString(responseString);
    }

    private static UrlHelper GetUrlHelper()
    {
        return new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an absolute version of the specified url relative to the current requests url root.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="thisHelper">The Url helper instance that this method extends.</param>
    /// <param name="url">The url to get an absolute version of.</param>
    /// <returns>An absolute version of the specified url relative to the current requests url root.</returns>
    public static string Absolute(this UrlHelper thisHelper, string url)
    {
        //only make the url absolute if it isn't already
        if (!url.Contains("://"))
        {
            return string.Format("http://{0}{1}", thisHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority, thisHelper.Content(url));
        }
        else
        {
            return url;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the authentication cookie of the specified request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request to set the cookie for.</param>
    /// <param name="authenticationCookie">(Optional) The cookie to add to the request, if not specified defaults 
    /// to the cookie of the user currently logged into the site.</param>
    public static void SetAuthenticationCookie(this HttpWebRequest request, Cookie authenticationCookie = null)
    {
        if (authenticationCookie == null)
        {
            //add the current authentication cookie to the request
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            authenticationCookie = new System.Net.Cookie
            (
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                cookie.Value,
                cookie.Path,
                FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
            );
        }

        request.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(authenticationCookie);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the response string from the specified request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request to get the response string from.</param>
    /// <returns>The response string from the specified request.</returns>
    public static string GetResponseString(this System.Net.WebRequest request)
    {
        System.Net.WebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException webException)
        {
            response = webException.Response;
            throw;
        }

        return GetResponseString(response);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the response string from the specified response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">The response to get the response string from.</param>
    /// <returns>The response string from the specified response.</returns>
    public static string GetResponseString(this System.Net.WebResponse response)
    {
        using (var responseTextStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return responseTextStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```